# Saving custom product attribute from edit page in Magento 2.1

Tags: product, magento-2.1, custom-attributes

I've created a custom menu item for the product edit page, and now I'm trying to save it.

[image: Custom tab]

The string "theducksflyatmidnight" appears nowhere in the database after saving. I've also stepped through my save-product observer with a debugger, and I can't find "theducksflyatmidnight" anywhere within the product object.

I've been studying some Vendor/Module/Setup code in Magento 2 core. Do I have to specify my custom attribute there? And then it will be saved upon saving the product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suspicion was correct; I needed to create a custom attribute using Vendor/Module/Setup/InstallData.php. I populated the select element using a source class in the attribute.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'product_profile',
            [
                'group' => 'My Group',
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\ProfileSelect',
                'label' => 'Profile',
                'required' => false,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```